# How to place content withing UIView boundaries

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm new in the swift/iOS application development, I'm currently working on an app for which I need to create the layout programmatically. My app contains a navigation bar at the top and a UIView object, where I'm rendering the controls. The issue I have is that I'm not exactly sure of the height of the navigation bar, so when rendering some controls are currently bellow the navigation bar, and the user cannot see them.
I could easily set a hard-coded height, but then it doesn't work properly across devices.
My best scenario really would be to get the position of the UIView object and place all I need within those boundaries, or to tell my object (e.g. UILabel) to position relative to the UIView.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use AutoLayouts: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html ; Also why do you need to build the layout programmatically? Is it because you want the layout to be aligned based on a device or is it the project's requirement? If it is the former, AutoLayout will make the layouting a piece of cake.

Comment: AutoLayouts could be the answer, I'll try it now. The reason why I need to do it programmatically is because the number of objects on the screen will depend on configuration on the DB, I need to build a grid of labels, it could be 4x4, 4x5, 5x4,8x8.... etc.

Comment: If you're making a grid of unknown dimensions, you might want to use a collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the frame of the navigation bar from your `UIViewController`, which is itself a `UIView` subclass, thusly:

```
CGRect navigationFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
```